# Runtime event listener works, but not object (LUA, SUBLIME TEXT 3, CORONA SDK)

Tags: lua, coronasdk, lua-table, event-listener

Related to a previous topic, helpfully answered by Piglet who directed me to documentation in this question: [Using a table in Lua to display text isn't working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43583538/using-a-table-in-lua-to-display-text-isnt-working)... for reference.

Because of how long the project has taken me, I decided to rework a good chunk of the program in order to meet my deadline. I used the documentation's help to properly fix the .text display. However, I should have had a functional changing "vnText" object that I could adjust the text of. However... it only works when I use Runtime event listener, and not the object itself.

While I am perfectly happy using the Runtime event listener to complete my project by the deadline, I would like to know *why* object:addEventListener didn't work as usual. Is there something I am missing in my code, something that Runtime accomplished that clicking on "textRect" won't?

The line in particular is

```
Runtime:addEventListener("tap", changePage)
```

It works perfectly now when I run it. The values are drawn from the table, the command print("change text") is displayed.

The object I tried to use in its place was textRect, which is defined earlier on in the program, a couple tables above. That didn't work to draw the text out and put it in the text. But Runtime did and I, for the life of me, cannot understand why.

HOWEVER, an interesting fact is that when I used textRect, "change text" was printed. But the function didn't change vnText.text...? Which is the whole reason I wrote up the program.

I have scoured documentation and other threads hoping to find an answer to this. The code, however, is much more complicated than my own level, since I'm just a high school student learning from class powerpoints ; right now I'm just searching for an answer as to why Runtime works? And if there is anything I can do to make the object work instead.

Thanks for your help, members of Stack Overflow! You all have helped me to learn tons in the past month.

```
local store = require( "plugin.google.iap.v3" )
local composer = require("composer")
local scene = composer.newScene()

display.setStatusBar( display.HiddenStatusBar )  -- Removes status bar
coins = 5 --[[variable that defines the number of coins player has in the game. It will be different 
in a stand alone game, but as a small app meant to demonstrate function, it's necessary to start off
with a small, defined number in the beginning.]]

local logo = display.newImage("/Images/logo.png", 155, 275) --code for my personal logo, drawn by me. 
--Not actually showcased in the video because of time limit.
logo.alpha = 0

local function makeTitleTrue() --this function makes the title true once the logo has been shown and faded out
    logo:removeSelf() -- removes logo from screen
    print("menu should be TRUE")
    titleScreen() -- calls function titleScreen (which is thetitle menu)
end

local function fadeOut()
    transition.to(logo, {time = 1000, alpha = 0, onComplete = makeTitleTrue})
end

transition.to(logo, {time = 1000, alpha = 1, onComplete = fadeOut}) -- end of logo code

function titleScreen() -- beginning of title code, which is not managed as a separate scene
    title = true 
    titleImg = display.newImage("/Images/vn_bg.png", 155, 275)
    --titleWords = display.newImage("/Images/TitleWords.png", 155, 275)

    --particles that flow across the screen as a cool effect. fix to flow towards the upper right corner.
    local flare = display.newImage("/Images/flare2.png", 40, 30)
    flare.xScale = .5
    flare.yScale = .5
    local flare2 = display.newImage("/Images/flare2.png", 400, 70)
    flare2.xScale = .6
    flare2.yScale = .6
    local flare3 = display.newImage("/Images/flare2.png", -30, 100)
    flare3.xScale = .4
    flare3.yScale = .4
    local flare4 = display.newImage("/Images/flare2.png", 100, 400)
    flare4.xScale = .4
    flare4.yScale = .4
    local flare5 = display.newImage("/Images/flare2.png", 400, 400)
    flare5.xScale = .3
    flare5.yScale = .3
    local flare6 = display.newImage("/Images/flare2.png", 250, 200)
    flare6.xScale = .3
    flare6.yScale = .3

    local function moveFlare1() 
        transition.to(flare, {time=2000, x = math.random(-100, 450), y = math.random(-100, 700), onComplete = moveFlare1})
    end
    local function moveFlare2()
        transition.to(flare2, {time=2000, x = math.random(-100, 450), y = math.random(-100, 700), onComplete = moveFlare2})
    end 
    local function moveFlare3()
        transition.to(flare3, {time=2000, x = math.random(-100, 450), y = math.random(-100, 700), onComplete = moveFlare3})
    end
    local function moveFlare4()
        transition.to(flare4, {time=2000, x = math.random(-100, 450), y = math.random(-100, 700), onComplete = moveFlare4})
    end 
    local function moveFlare5()
        transition.to(flare5, {time=2000, x = math.random(-100, 450), y = math.random(-100, 700), onComplete = moveFlare5})
    end 
    local function moveFlare6()
        transition.to(flare6, {time=2000, x = math.random(-100, 450), y = math.random(-100, 700), onComplete = moveFlare6})
    end 
    transition.to(flare, {time=2000, x = math.random(-100, 450), y = math.random(-100, 700), onComplete = moveFlare1})
    transition.to(flare2, {time=2500, x = math.random(-100, 450), y = math.random(-100, 700), onComplete = moveFlare2}) 
    transition.to(flare3, {time=2000, x = math.random(-100, 450), y = math.random(-100, 700), onComplete = moveFlare3}) 
    transition.to(flare4, {time=2000, x = math.random(-100, 450), y = math.random(-100, 700), onComplete = moveFlare4}) 
    transition.to(flare5, {time=2000, x = math.random(-100, 450), y = math.random(-100, 700), onComplete = moveFlare5}) 
    transition.to(flare6, {time=2000, x = math.random(-100, 450), y = math.random(-100, 700), onComplete = moveFlare6}) 

    --add options that can when the screen is tapped, tap on an option twice to select
    --local newGame_op = display.newImage("", )
    --local cont_op = display.newImage("", )
    --local coin_op = display.newImage("",)
    --local end_op = display.newImage("",)
        -- start story
        -- continue story
        -- coin gambling
        -- end game

    if (title == true) then
        Runtime:addEventListener("tap", sceneVN)
    end

    --coin_op:addEventListener("tap", coinShop)
end

function forceQuit()
    function quit() 
        os.exit() 
        end 
        timer.performWithDelay(1000,quit)
    end

function sceneVNChapter2()
    return
end

function sceneVN() -- the actual visual novel code itself
    display.remove(titleImg)
    display.remove(flare)
    display.remove(flare2)
    display.remove(flare3)
    display.remove(flare4)
    display.remove(flare5)
    display.remove(flare6)
    title = false
    Runtime:removeEventListener()

    page = 0

    local coinSheetData =
    {
        width = 32,
        height = 32,
        numFrames = 8,
    }

    local coinimageSheet = graphics.newImageSheet( "/Images/spinning_coin.png", coinSheetData )

    local sequenceData =
    {
        name= "spinning_coin",
        start = 1, 
        count = 8,
        time = 1000,
        loopCount = 0
    }

    --the properties of the name plate that can be changed ingame by using ".text" property
    local nameOptions = 
    {
        text = "Frankenstein",  
        x = 165,
        y = 450,
        width = 310,
        font = "Charlesworth.ttf",
        fontSize = 22,
        align = "left"
    }
    local bg = display.newImage("/Images/bg4.jpg", 155, 275)
    local bust_display = display.newImage( "/Images/f_bust1.png", 155, 223 )
    textRect = display.newRect(155, 525, 325, 200)
    textRect:setFillColor(.02, .02, .02)
    textRect.alpha = .9

    local frames = display.newImage("/Images/windowframes_gold.png", 155, 275)
    display.newText(nameOptions)

    local scriptIntro =
    {
        [1] = "\"I see. So I\'m supposed to pretend I am\na character in a multi-chapter phone\napp that you\'ve been reading...\"",
        [2] = "\"So the purpose of this game is to flirt\nwith me until the meter fills up, and\nyou earn enough coins for a date?\"",
        [3] = "\"Then let's see how far you get. Charm\nme by picking the right compliments\nto praise me, my lady.\"",
        [4] = "\"When the meter is full, you'll be able\nto ask me on a date to progress the\ngame.\"",
        [5] = "\"Let's start the game, then... Can you\ncharm me, the butler of the Raizel\nhousehold?\""
    }

    vnText = display.newText("\"Good evening. This is a demonstration\nof a visual novel and minigame...\"", 160, 500, "Goudy Old Style Regular.ttf", 17)
    vnText.x = 20 ; vnText.y = 495
    vnText:setFillColor( 1, 1, 1 )
    vnText.anchorX = 0

    local function changePage()
        page = page + 1
        print("change text")
        vnText.text = scriptIntro[page]
    end

    Runtime:addEventListener("tap", changePage)

    function choiceGame()
        local c_Complimented = {
            [1] = "\"Aha... thank you so much. I do my best.\"",
            [2] = "\"Ah, please, you flatter me too much! I\ncannot even begin to compare with\nyour praises.\"",
            [3] = "\"You're making me blush, my lady. Where\ndid you learn such charm?\"",
            [4] = "\"I really don't know what to say... how\nsweet.\""
        }

        local c_Insulted = {
            [1] = "\"Is that really your best attempt at a\nflirt? Pathetic...\"",
            [2] = "\"A butler of the Raizel household can\'t\n even begin to contemplate the idea\n of dating you.\"",
            [3] = "\"Haha... what a wonderful choice... NOT.\nTry again, darling.\"",
            [4] = "\"Such insults are below even your calibre,\n my lady.\""
        }

        local function optionChosen()
            if (compliment == true) then 
                displayStatus.text = c_Complimented[math.random(1,4)]
            else
                displayStatus.text = c_Insulted[math.random(1,4)]
            end
        end 

        displayStatus = display.newText("Haha... I look forward to your attempts\nat flirting with me.", 160, 500, "Goudy Old Style Regular.ttf", 17)

        Runtime:addEventListener("tap", optionChosen)
    end -- end of choice game

    local function flirtComplete()
        local scriptComplete = 
        {
            [1] = "\"Then, seeing as this is a simulation of\n a visual novel dating sim, I have no\n choice but to ask you...\"",
            [2] = "\"My lady, would you go on a date with me?\nFrankenstein... butler of the finest noble,\nCadis Etrama di Raizel?\"",
            [3] = "\"So, have you made a decision about whether\nyou would like to date yet?\""
        }
    end

    if (coins < 10) then
        coinsDigits = 2
    else 
        if (coins > 9) and (coins < 100) then 
            coinsDigits = 3
        else 
            if (coins > 99) and (coins < 1000) then 
                coinsDigits = 4
            else 
                if (coins > 999) and (coins < 10000) then 
                    coinsDigits = 5
                else 
                    if (coins > 9999) and (coins < 100000) then
                        coinsDigits = 6
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end

    cooin = display.newSprite(coinimageSheet, sequenceData)
    cooin.x = 25
    cooin.y = 30
    cooin:play()

    coinText = display.newText("1", 57 + 4 * coinsDigits, 32, "VCR_OSD_MONO_1.001.ttf", 25)
    coinText.text = coins
    coinTimer = timer.performWithDelay(2000, cooin, 1)
end

function choiceMade( event ) --the scenes where all the choices are made
    if (event.action == "clicked") then 
        local i = event.index
        if (i == 1) then 
            Runtime:removeEventListener()
            titleScreen()
            else
                if (i == 2) then 
                    system.openURL( "https://www.paypal.com/us/home" )
                else
                    if (i == 3) then 
                        return 
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end -- end of choice scenes

function Outofcoins()
--native alert lack of zero coins
    local alertMessage = "Uh oh, looks like you've run out of coins! Would you like to keep flirting, or buy more?"
    native.showAlert( "Out of coins!", alertMessage, {"Continue flirting", "Purchase coins", "Exit to Menu"}, choiceMade)
end 


function sceneGambleStart()

    function earntCoins()
        numberEarnt = 0
        local coinsGot = display.newImage("/Images/coins_gold.png", 155, 275)
        coinsGot.alpha = 0

        local function fadeOutCoinsEart()
            transition.to(logo, {time = 2000, alpha = 0})
            display.remove(coinsGot)
        end

        local transitionFade = transition.to(logo, {time = 2000, alpha = 1, onComplete = fadeOutCoinsEarnt})
        timer.performWithDelay(2000, transitionFade, 1)
        coinText.text = coins + numberEarnt
    end
end
```

Comment: Is there a reason when you are not setting up your scene with the usual methods (`scene:create()`, `scene:show()`, etc.) as described in the [scene template](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/composer/index.html#template).

Comment: It could be a scope problem.  I would do all this set up in `scene:create()` and declare all the variables that will hold display objects as `local` at the top of that method.  Then when you declare the listener functions later on (`local function changePage`, etc.) you know your DisplayObjects are in scope.

Comment: display.newText(nameOptions) is not being assigned to anything BTW

Comment: Ah, I hadn't known about the scene template. My code is how the teacher has always showed us. Her style of setting up scenes carried over from past classes in Javascript, so I never thought there would be another way... Looking at the link you sent me, we hardly learnt any of the commands involved. "if ( phase == "will" )" and "( phase == "did" )", as well as the style of setting up the functions -- we have never used colons in our function names, nor did we ever use "self.view". It's still feasible for me to finish the program as is, but after the project I'll try this suggestion! Thanks!

Comment: I see. So all this code is in your `main.lua`?  I don't mean to suggest that that is the reason for your problem with `vnText`.

Answer (score 1):

As your code is, `textRect` and `vnText` are both global in scope but `scriptIntro` is `local` and declared after `textRect`.  So if you tried to add a `tap` listener to `textRect` in which you refer to `scriptIntro`, it wouldn't work.  In fact, all of these variables could be `local`; just declare them in the right order:

```
local scriptIntro = ...  -- an array of strings

local vnText = display.newText(...
vnText.text = scriptIntro[1]

local n = 1
local textRect = display.newRect(...
function textRect:tap( event )
    n = n + 1
    if n > #scriptIntro then
        n = 1
    end
    vnText.text = scriptIntro[n]
    return true
end
textRect:addEventListener( "tap", textRect )
```